# crystal report - how to print in 2 column

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have database that connect to crystal report.
i have only one field.
how i can print this field in 2 column

ex:

```
col1 ---- clo2

1 --------- 4

2 --------- 5

3 --------- 6
```

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

if the value of the column is int you can do it with select from database like this

```
SELECT
      case WHEN value / 2 = 0 THEN value ELSE null END AS col1,
      case WHEN value / 2 = 1 THEN value ELSE null END AS col2
FROM table
```

If i haven't understand the problem please explain more. Also you can bind crystal reports to ADO .Net dataset then you can do this split in you code using a loop.

Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: thank's for the help, what i mean is that i have database that has one field, and i want to split this field in crystal report to 2 columns that will shows in the page

Comment: The you can create in your c# you can create DataTable with two columns and then loop through the data selected from the DB and put the value from the value into first or second column, Then put this DataTable into DataSet and use the DataSet as DataSource for the crystal report. This is the best thing to do. Best Regards, iordan

Answer (score 0):

To create a multiple-column report:

1.Open the report you want to format with multiple columns.

2.On the Report menu, click Section Expert.

3.In the Section Expert, highlight Details, and then select Format with Multiple Columns. 
A Layout tab is added to the Section Expert.

4.Click the Layout tab and set the Width you want your column to be. 
Keep in mind the width of your paper when deciding your column width. For example, if you have three fields in your Details section, and they take up four inches of space, limit the width of the column to under four and a half inches so that all the field information can be seen.

5.Set the Horizontal and/or Vertical gap you want to maintain between each record in your column.

6.In the Printing Direction area, choose a direction.

7.If the report you're formatting contains grouping, select Format Groups with multiple column.

8.Click OK.

When you preview the report, you'll see that the field headers appear only for the first column. To have field headers for the second column, insert a text object.